# What's the difference between nil and NSBundle in UIStoryboard()?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, nsbundle

I have seen both of these being used a lot but I can't find what the difference is:

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
```

So what's the difference between setting bundle to `nil` or to `NSBundle.mainBundle()`?

Comment: Read the docs for `UIStoryboard()`. It tells you.

Comment: @Senseful The docs are quite clear. If you pass `nil`, it uses the main bundle. And what does `NSBundle.mainBundle()` represent? The main bundle.

Comment: @rmaddy whoops, read that wrong, never mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there is no difference between those two. Whether you specify `nil` or `NSBundle.mainBundle()` both will refer to main bundle.

> The bundle containing the storyboard file and its related resources.
>   If you specify nil, this method looks in the main bundle of the
>   current application.

Reference: [UIStoryboard Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:)

The `bundle:` parameter will become useful when you need to access the info from another bundle, apart from `mainBundle()`. For example, many third-party libraries ship with their own bundle for wrapping up the resources used by that particular library. So if you want to access those resources you need to refer that bundle.